# how to update(edit) multiple images(file) in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to update the multiple images in codeigniter , when i submit the form and also upload the new images on submit . This is working only for uploading new multiple images
this is my controller file

public function product_edit($product_id){

```
    $data["data"] = $this->Menu_management_model->getCat();
    $this->load->view('header',$data);
    $category_id= $this->uri->segment(4);
    $viewData['data'] = $this->Menu_management_model->getProduct($id='',$product_id);
    $viewData['image'] = $this->Menu_management_model->getProductPhoto($id='',$product_id);
    $this->load->view('products/product_edit', $viewData);
    $updateData = array(
        'product_name' => $this->input->post('product_name'),
        'product_description'=> $this->input->post('product_description'),
    );
    if($this->input->post('update_product')){
        $sub_category_id= $this->input->post('sub_category_id');
        $files = $_FILES;
        if(!empty($files['product_photo']['name'])){
            $count = count($_FILES['product_photo']['name']);
            for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
                $_FILES['product_photo']['name']= $files['product_photo']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['product_photo']['tmp_name']= $files['product_photo']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['product_photo']['size']= $files['product_photo']['size'][$i];
                $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/uploads/products/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                $this->upload->do_upload('product_photo');
                $fileName = $this->upload->data('file_name');
                $images[] = $fileName;
            }
            $fileName = implode(',',$images);
            $update= $this->Menu_management_model->updateProduct($product_id,$updateData,$fileName,$sub_category_id,$category_id);

        }
```

}

this is my model

public function updateProduct($product_id,$updateData,$filename,$sub_category_id,$category_id){

```
    $update= $this->db->update('products', $updateData, array('product_id'=>$product_id));
    if($filename!='' ){
        $filename1 = explode(',',$filename);
        foreach($filename1 as $file){
            $file_data = array(
                'product_photo' => $file,
                'product_id' => $product_id,
                'sub_category_id'=>$sub_category_id,
                'category_id'=>$category_id
            );
            $update = $this->db->insert('product_images', $file_data);
        }
    }
    return $update?true:false;
}
```

this my view page so please check this and help me

```
<form id="add_produc" method="post" class="addProduct" name="add_produc" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="head" colspan="2">Edit</th>
                                </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label for="Name">Name:</label></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="product_name" value="<?= $data['product_name']?>" id="product_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td> <label for="Description">Description:</label> </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="product_description" value="<?= $data['product_description']?>" id="product_description" class="form-control" placeholder="description">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr >
                                        <td><label for="Photo">Photo:</label> </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div id="addField0">
                                                <input type="file" name="product_photo[]"   id="product_photo" class="form-control" accept="image/*"><br>
                                            </div>
                                            <button id="add-more-edit" name="add-more-edit" class="btn btn-primary">Add More</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                        if(!empty($image)){
                                            foreach ($image as $result){
                                    ?>
                                    <tr class='imagelocation<?= $result->product_image_id ?>'>
                                        <td colspan="2" align='center'>
                                            <input type="text" name="product_image_id" value="<?= $result->product_image_id?>" id="product_image_id" class="form-control">
                                            <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control images<?php echo $result->product_image_id ?>" accept="image/*" onchange="javascript:editimage(<?php echo $result->product_image_id ?>)">

                                            <img class='img-rounded' height="50" width="50" src="<?= base_url('/assets/uploads/products/'.$result->product_photo)?>" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                            <span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript:deleteimage(<?php echo $result->product_image_id ?>)">X</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                            }
                                        }else{
                                            echo '<div class="empty">No Products Found...!</div>';
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="sub_category_id" value="<?= $data['sub_category_id']?>" id="sub_category_name" class="form-control">
                                            <input type="submit" name="update_product" id="update_product" class="btn btn-info btn-small" value="Update">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                            </table>
</form>
```

Comment: What errors you are getting?

Comment: there is a loop in my view page.. for retriev image . that images i should update no errors getting

Comment: When you say update, do you mean, delete all the previous images and only use the "new" ones?

Comment: yes..! but it should replace the image with same id